# Magento 2, How to add a control in custom option in configuration product

Tags: magento2.2, configurable-product, custom-options

Using `Magento 2`, `Configuration Product`, `Custom Option`. I need to add **check-box** for *hide custom option item price* in front page.

**Backend**

> **Catalog -> Configuration Product**
>   [image]

**Front**

> **Product option in will show like this *if check hide price* from back-end**
>   [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a module with name **STech_Hide** and create the files like below steps:

**Step 1:**
Create **registration.php** under:

> app/code/STech/Hide/registration.php

with below content:

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'STech_Hide',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step 2:**
Create **module.xml** under:

> app/code/STech/Hide/etc/module.xml

with below content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="STech_Hide" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Step 3:
Create **di.xml** under:

> app/code/STech/Hide/etc/di.xml

with below content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions" type="STech\Hide\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions" />
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" type="STech\Hide\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" />
</config>
```

**Step 4:**
Create **Select.php** under:

> app/code/STech/Hide/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php

with below content:

```
<?php
namespace STech\Hide\Block\Product\View\Options\Type;

class Select extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select
{
    public function getValuesHtml()
    {
        $_option = $this->getOption();
        $configValue = $this->getProduct()->getPreconfiguredValues()->getData('options/' . $_option->getId());
        $store = $this->getProduct()->getStore();

        $this->setSkipJsReloadPrice(1);
        // Remove inline prototype onclick and onchange events

        if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_DROP_DOWN ||
            $_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_MULTIPLE
        ) {
            $require = $_option->getIsRequire() ? ' required' : '';
            $extraParams = '';
            $select = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Select::class
            )->setData(
                [
                    'id' => 'select_' . $_option->getId(),
                    'class' => $require . ' product-custom-option admin__control-select'
                ]
            );
            if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_DROP_DOWN) {
                $select->setName('options[' . $_option->getId() . ']')->addOption('', __('-- Please Select --'));
            } else {
                $select->setName('options[' . $_option->getId() . '][]');
                $select->setClass('multiselect admin__control-multiselect' . $require . ' product-custom-option');
            }
            foreach ($_option->getValues() as $_value) {
                $priceStr = $this->_formatPrice(
                    [
                        'is_percent' => $_value->getPriceType() == 'percent',
                        'pricing_value' => $_value->getPrice($_value->getPriceType() == 'percent'),
                    ],
                    false
                );
                $select->addOption(
                    $_value->getOptionTypeId(),
                    $_value->getTitle() . ' ' . strip_tags($priceStr) . '',
                    ['price' => $this->pricingHelper->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false)]
                );
            }
            if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_MULTIPLE) {
                $extraParams = ' multiple="multiple"';
            }
            if (!$this->getSkipJsReloadPrice()) {
                $extraParams .= ' onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()"';
            }
            $extraParams .= ' data-selector="' . $select->getName() . '"';
            $select->setExtraParams($extraParams);

            if ($configValue) {
                $select->setValue($configValue);
            }

            return $select->getHtml();
        }

        if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_RADIO ||
            $_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_CHECKBOX
        ) {
            $selectHtml = '<div class="options-list nested" id="options-' . $_option->getId() . '-list">';
            $require = $_option->getIsRequire() ? ' required' : '';
            $arraySign = '';
            switch ($_option->getType()) {
                case \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_RADIO:
                    $type = 'radio';
                    $class = 'radio admin__control-radio';
                    if (!$_option->getIsRequire()) {
                        $selectHtml .= '<div class="field choice admin__field admin__field-option">' .
                            '<input type="radio" id="options_' .
                            $_option->getId() .
                            '" class="' .
                            $class .
                            ' product-custom-option" name="options[' .
                            $_option->getId() .
                            ']"' .
                            ' data-selector="options[' . $_option->getId() . ']"' .
                            ($this->getSkipJsReloadPrice() ? '' : ' onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()"') .
                            ' value="" checked="checked" /><label class="label admin__field-label" for="options_' .
                            $_option->getId() .
                            '"><span>' .
                            __('None') . '</span></label></div>';
                    }
                    break;
                case \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_CHECKBOX:
                    $type = 'checkbox';
                    $class = 'checkbox admin__control-checkbox';
                    $arraySign = '[]';
                    break;
            }
            $count = 1;
            foreach ($_option->getValues() as $_value) {
                $count++;

                $priceStr = $this->_formatPrice(
                    [
                        'is_percent' => $_value->getPriceType() == 'percent',
                        'pricing_value' => $_value->getPrice($_value->getPriceType() == 'percent'),
                    ]
                );

                $htmlValue = $_value->getOptionTypeId();
                if ($arraySign) {
                    $checked = is_array($configValue) && in_array($htmlValue, $configValue) ? 'checked' : '';
                } else {
                    $checked = $configValue == $htmlValue ? 'checked' : '';
                }

                $dataSelector = 'options[' . $_option->getId() . ']';
                if ($arraySign) {
                    $dataSelector .= '[' . $htmlValue . ']';
                }

                if($_option->getHidePrice()){
                    $priceStr = '';
                }

                $selectHtml .= '<div class="field choice admin__field admin__field-option' .
                    $require .
                    '">' .
                    '<input type="' .
                    $type .
                    '" class="' .
                    $class .
                    ' ' .
                    $require .
                    ' product-custom-option"' .
                    ($this->getSkipJsReloadPrice() ? '' : ' onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()"') .
                    ' name="options[' .
                    $_option->getId() .
                    ']' .
                    $arraySign .
                    '" id="options_' .
                    $_option->getId() .
                    '_' .
                    $count .
                    '" value="' .
                    $htmlValue .
                    '" ' .
                    $checked .
                    ' data-selector="' . $dataSelector . '"' .
                    ' price="' .
                    $this->pricingHelper->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false) .
                    '" />' .
                    '<label class="label admin__field-label" for="options_' .
                    $_option->getId() .
                    '_' .
                    $count .
                    '"><span>' .
                    $_value->getTitle() .
                    '</span> ' .
                    $priceStr .
                    '</label>';
                $selectHtml .= '</div>';
            }
            $selectHtml .= '</div>';

            return $selectHtml;
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 5:**
Create **InstallSchema.php** under:

> app/code/STech/Hide/Setup/InstallSchema.php

with below content:

```
<?php
namespace STech\Hide\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        $tableName = $installer->getTable('catalog_product_option');
        $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $tableName,
            'hide_price',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                'length' => 10,
                'nullable' => true,
                'after' => 'is_require',
                'default' => 0,
                'comment' => 'Hide Price',
            ]
        );
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

**Step 6:**
Create **CustomOptions.php** under:

> app/code/STech/Hide/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/CustomOptions.php

with below content:

```
<?php
namespace STech\Hide\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Ui\Component\Container;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Checkbox;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Text;


class CustomOptions extends \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions
{
    /**#@+
     * Field values
     */
    const FIELD_HIDE_PRICE_NAME = 'hide_price';
    /**#@-*/

    protected function getCommonContainerConfig($sortOrder)
    {
        $commonContainer = [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'componentType' => Container::NAME,
                        'formElement' => Container::NAME,
                        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/group',
                        'breakLine' => false,
                        'showLabel' => false,
                        'additionalClasses' => 'admin__field-group-columns admin__control-group-equal',
                        'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'children' => [
                static::FIELD_OPTION_ID => $this->getOptionIdFieldConfig(10),
                static::FIELD_TITLE_NAME => $this->getTitleFieldConfig(
                    20,
                    [
                        'arguments' => [
                            'data' => [
                                'config' => [
                                    'label' => __('Option Title'),
                                    'component' => 'Magento_Catalog/component/static-type-input',
                                    'valueUpdate' => 'input',
                                    'imports' => [
                                        'optionId' => '${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.option_id',
                                        'isUseDefault' => '${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.is_use_default'
                                    ]
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ]
                ),
                static::FIELD_TYPE_NAME => $this->getTypeFieldConfig(30),
                static::FIELD_IS_REQUIRE_NAME => $this->getIsRequireFieldConfig(40),
                static::FIELD_HIDE_PRICE_NAME => $this->getHidePriceFieldConfig(50)
            ]
        ];

        if ($this->locator->getProduct()->getStoreId()) {
            $useDefaultConfig = [
                'service' => [
                    'template' => 'Magento_Catalog/form/element/helper/custom-option-service',
                ]
            ];
            $titlePath = $this->arrayManager->findPath(static::FIELD_TITLE_NAME, $commonContainer, null)
                . static::META_CONFIG_PATH;
            $commonContainer = $this->arrayManager->merge($titlePath, $commonContainer, $useDefaultConfig);
        }

        return $commonContainer;
    }

    protected function getHidePriceFieldConfig($sortOrder)
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'label' => __('Hide Price'),
                        'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                        'formElement' => Checkbox::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => static::FIELD_HIDE_PRICE_NAME,
                        'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                        'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                        'value' => '1',
                        'valueMap' => [
                            'true' => '1',
                            'false' => '0'
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

}
```

Run setup upgrade, di compile and other required commands and test.

Comment: It work, I so much Mr. Sukumar Gorai.

Comment: Hello, sir @Sukumar. I saw 
/**#@+
     * Field values
     */

How it work?

Comment: Not understand what you are asking

Comment: Why used '
/**#@+
     * Field values
     */
' in the CustomOptions class? Plz. explain me sir.

Comment: That is a constant which is used in that class. If you check the core class of custom option they have the same logic.

Comment: That just simple *constant*?

Comment: Yes simple constant which is used in this class only.